# How to fetch object id from parse Ios

Tags: swift, parse-platform

**Code**

```
let number=UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "phone")
let s=PFQuery(className: "Customer")
s.whereKey("phonenumber", equalTo:number!)
s.getFirstObjectInBackground(block: { (gameScore: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
        //The query returned an error
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        //The object has been retrieved
        print(gameScore?.objectId)
    }
})
```

I need to fetch object id in a row where it matches my phone number, How do I do that?

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Do you get an error or nothing back or a crash?

Comment: error "no results matches your query"

Comment: error "no results matches your query"

Comment: Then there is hardly anything we can help you with, you need to compare your argument with what you have on server. The only advice I can give is not to force unwrap ’number’

Answer (score 0):

I made mistake while calling the query , query needs only Int but iam sending Any data type

```
 let number=UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "phone") as? String
   let Stringtonumber=Int(number!)
let s=PFQuery(className: "Customer")
s.whereKey("phonenumber", equalTo:Stringtonumber)
s.getFirstObjectInBackground(block: { (gameScore: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
        //The query returned an error
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        //The object has been retrieved
        print(gameScore?.objectId)
    }
})
```